# Ultimate extinction certain if $\lambda \le 1$ in a (Poisson) branching process?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution

I have a branching process where each individual has a

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \lambda^k \frac{e^{-\lambda}}{k!}$$

(Poisson) probability of producing $k$ descendants. I want to show that the probability of ultimate extinction is certain if $\lambda \le 1$.

Well the expected value $E[Z_n]$ of the $n$-th generation will be $\lambda^n$. Therefore, as we go towards infinity if, $\lambda < 1$ then $E[Z_n] = 0$. So we expect that eventually there will be $0$ individuals, i.e. extinction will have occurred.

But if $\lambda = 1$, then $E[Z_n] = 1 \ne 0$. So extinction doesn't occur here?

Where am I going wrong? **Am I going about this in the right way by checking the expected value or should I be using some other method to do determine that the probability of ultimate extinction is certain if $\lambda \le 1$?**

Comment: By "branching process" do you mean the Galton-Watson process? If so you can analyze the process using probability generating functions. A good reference is Sidney Resnick's "Adventures In Stochastic Processes."

Comment: I had calculated the probability generating function here as $G(s) = e^{\lambda s - \lambda}$. I am not sure of how you would apply it to answer my question though.

Comment: The difference between the $\lambda \lt 1$ and $\lambda =1$ cases is similar to the Gambler's Ruin analysis with an unfair coin biased against the gambler and a fair coin.  Both have a probability of $1$ of eventual extinction/ruin, but in the worse case the expected time for this to happen is finite, and in the better case infinite.  Your argument for eventual almost-certain extinction when $\lambda \lt 1$ is correct given that the population is an integer with declining expectation, but it is a one-way implication.

Comment: The probability of having $k$ descendants would be $\lambda^k\dfrac{e^{-\lambda}}{k!}$, not the _sum_ of all of those. $\qquad$

Comment: Got something from the answer below?

Answer (score 4):

Why not apply *the general argument*, valid for every subcritical or critical branching process?

Conditionally on $Z_1=k$, the probability to go extinct is $\theta^k$, where $\theta$ is the probability that the whole process, starting from $Z_0=1$, goes extinct. Thus, $$\theta=\sum_kP(Z_1=k)\theta^k=G(\theta),\qquad G(s)=E(s^{Z_1}),$$ where $G$ denotes the generating function of the number of offspring of each individual. If $E(Z_1)\leqslant1$ (and $P(Z_1=1)\ne1$), the function $G$ is strictly convex with $G'(1)\leqslant1$ hence $G(t)\gt t$ for every $t$ in $[0,1)$, in particular, $\theta=1$.

$\hspace{25ex}$[image]

Source: Any textbook on branching processes (which one are you following?).

Note: The argument in your question, based on the expectations, works when $\lambda\lt1$ but it needs to be made more precise. Indeed, $E(Z_n)\to0$ and, *because $Z_n$ is nonnegative and integer valued*, $Z_n\geqslant\mathbf 1_{Z_n\ne0}$ almost surely hence $P(Z_n\ne0)\leqslant E(Z_n)$ and one knows that $P(Z_n\ne0)\to0$. Note that the argument would fail in general for real valued random variables.

Comment: Cool, I'll look through that next week, tied up with other exams at the moment.